# How to swap two objects' positions on a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, algorithm-animation

I am working on a sorting visualization program with tkinter using the height of different rectangles. I was able to randomize the height of each rectangle, but now I am stuck trying to figure out how to switch the position of two rectangles with each other. I need to figure out how to do this before I can start trying to implement a sort.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Sorting')
window.geometry('600x400')

xstart = 5
xend = 15
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width='600', height='400')
canvas.pack()
barList = []
lengthList = []

for x in range(1,60):
    randomY = random.randint(1,390)
    bar = canvas.create_rectangle(xstart,randomY,xend,395, fill='red')
    barList.append(bar)
    xstart += 10
    xend +=10

for bar in barList:
    x = canvas.coords(bar)
    length = x[3]-x[1]
    lengthList.append(length)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where do you try to swap rectangle positions?

Comment: @alec_a I don't, I tried messing around with some ideas but in the end I couldn't figure how to implement anything for that

Comment: effbot.org: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) - `coords()` to get and set position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example to get you started: It swaps rectangle at position 10 and rectangle at position 20 upon clicking on the swap button.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def swap_two_pos(pos_0, pos_1):
    """This does the graphical swapping of the rectangles on the canvas
    by moving one rectangle to the location of the other, and vice versa
    """    
    x_00, _, x_01, _ = canvas.coords(pos_0)
    x_10, _, x_11, _ = canvas.coords(pos_1)
    # moves each rectangle to the x position of the other; y remains unchanged
    canvas.move(pos_0, x_10-x_00, 0)
    canvas.move(pos_1, x_01-x_11, 0)


def random_sort():
    """Not a sort yet, but you have the bare bones operations
    so the swap is executed
    """
    pos_0 = barList[10]
    pos_1 = barList[20]
    swap_two_pos(pos_0, pos_1)
    # it is necessary to swap the values in the list too
    barList[10], barList[20] = barList[20], barList[10]


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Sorting')
window.geometry('600x400')

# button to command the swap
tk.Button(window, text='swap', command=random_sort).pack()

xstart = 5
xend = 15
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width='600', height='400')
canvas.pack()
barList = []
lengthList = []

for x in range(1,60):
    randomY = random.randint(1,390)
    bar = canvas.create_rectangle(xstart, randomY, xend, 395, fill='red')
    barList.append(bar)
    xstart += 10
    xend +=10

for bar in barList:
    x = canvas.coords(bar)
    length = x[3]-x[1]
    lengthList.append(length)

# hardcoded colors so the swap is more visual
canvas.itemconfig(barList[10], fill='blue')
canvas.itemconfig(barList[20], fill='yellow')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I recommend using more useful variable names than `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. Using `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2` (or something similar) makes the code much more self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the suggestion @Bryan, I actually intended to change that, but somehow forgot.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it is exactly what I needed to understand